# Multiple Relational from 4 Table using equi join in Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, datatable

[image]

Sorry i really stuck at this time, sorry if my english is bad

what query i use for display the name of customer who ordered 'Desk' in Product Table, These four tables have a relations, it can be seen from their Primary and Foreign keys

found the answer to my questions and i can learn much from that answer literally

Answer (score 0):

```
   
   SELECT Customer.Nama, Product.product
   FROM Customer
    INNER JOIN Product
        ON Product.ProductID = Order_Line.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Order_Line
        ON Order_Line.OrderId = Order.OrderId
    INNER JOIN Order
        ON Order.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
   WHERE Product.product = 'Desk'
```